# Fancybox2: fixed width and dynamic height depending on content

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

i am using fancybox2 on ajax content and i'm trying to set the popup dimensions as following: 
fixed width but height according to the content. which means, if the content is "larger" than the screen's viewport, it should overflow and getting scrolled by the main document's scrollbar. i've tried autoScale but the popup always remains within the screen dimensions.
any ideas how to do it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If using fancybox v2.x set `fitToView` to `false` .... `autoScale` is for v1.3.4 and NOT compatible with v2.x